# Need to display top 3 highest number in multiple arrays

Tags: c, arrays, max, insertion-sort

Don't know how to find the top 3 highest number and how to display only the top 3 highest number

```
float feb10[] = { 25.0, 24.8, 24.8, 24.7, 25.1, 25.4, 25.1, 25.1, 25.0, 24.5, 24.3, 24.1 };

float feb11[] = { 23.8, 23.3, 22.9, 22.8, 22.9, 23.3, 23.1, 23.7, 23.0, 22.6, 22.9, 22.8 };

float feb12[] = { 22.8, 22.6, 22.8, 22.8, 24.2, 25.3, 24.8, 24.2, 24.2, 24.1, 24.7, 24.8 };

float feb13[] = { 24.9, 25.0, 24.9, 25.1, 25.4, 25.7, 25.9, 25.4, 25.1, 24.9, 25.2, 25.0 };

float feb14[] = { 25.0, 24.7, 24.6, 24.5, 25.3, 25.1, 25.2, 25.1, 24.9, 24.1, 24.1, 24.2 };
```

Results should be

```
1st highest is 25.9

2nd highest is 25.7

joint 3rd highest is 25.4
```

Comment: Can the maximum numbers have the same values (that is are duplicates allowed) or shall all three  maximum numbers have different values?

Comment: Build an array of the largest values in all arrays, sort it descending, take the top 3. If you need to keep the day info, then create an array of struct holding date and highest, sort descending by highest and take first 3.

Comment: Finding the highest numbers in multiple arrays is no different than finding the highest numbers in a single array. So start by writing code to find the three highest numbers in a single array.

Comment: how do i sort all the largest numbers from multiple arrays into one and displaying the top 3? @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Not going to work... All 3 largest elements might be very well in a single array. One needs to "flatten" the arrays into a one and then perform a simple scanning for 3 largest elements.

Comment: Can you please add here what all have you tried? Some reproducible piece of code would be a good starter place.

Comment: You don't need to sort anything. One simple way is to make three passes of the data. The first finds the highest value. The second finds the highest value that is less than the first. Similar the third. If you count duplicate occurrences of those highest values you can then report either way as suggested by Vlad. Having done that you can make it more efficient by making a single pass of the data.

Comment: @EugeneSh.good catch, I was under the impression he wanted the highest from 3 separate arrays... In that case you know the total number of elements, create an array to hold all elements and then sort that in descending order (using `qsort`) and then take the top 3 -- same comment regarding the struct applies, if needed.

Answer (score 3):

We, beginners, should help each other.:)

A simple way to do the task is to declare an array of the arrays.

Also to declare an array for the three largest elements. And then to use the insertion sort to include a current largest element to the array of the largest elements.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    double feb10[] = { 25.0, 24.8, 24.8, 24.7, 25.1, 25.4, 25.1, 25.1, 25.0, 24.5, 24.3, 24.1 };
    double feb11[] = { 23.8, 23.3, 22.9, 22.8, 22.9, 23.3, 23.1, 23.7, 23.0, 22.6, 22.9, 22.8 };
    double feb12[] = { 22.8, 22.6, 22.8, 22.8, 24.2, 25.3, 24.8, 24.2, 24.2, 24.1, 24.7, 24.8 };
    double feb13[] = { 24.9, 25.0, 24.9, 25.1, 25.4, 25.7, 25.9, 25.4, 25.1, 24.9, 25.2, 25.0 };
    double feb14[] = { 25.0, 24.7, 24.6, 24.5, 25.3, 25.1, 25.2, 25.1, 24.9, 24.1, 24.1, 24.2 };

    double * a[] = { feb10, feb11, feb12, feb13, feb14 };
    const size_t M = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    const size_t N = sizeof( feb10 ) / sizeof( *feb10 );

    enum { LARGEST_SIZE = 3 };  
    double max_values[LARGEST_SIZE] = { a[0][0] };
    size_t filled = 1;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            size_t pos = 0;
            while ( pos < filled && !( max_values[pos] < a[i][j] ) ) ++pos;

            if ( pos == filled )
            {
                // If the array of largest elements is not filled then
                // just append the array with the current largest element. 
                if ( filled != LARGEST_SIZE )
                {
                    max_values[filled++]  = a[i][j];
                }                   
            }
            else
            {
                // Here is used the insertion sort
                for ( size_t k = LARGEST_SIZE; --k != pos; ) max_values[k] = max_values[k-1];
                max_values[pos] = a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < LARGEST_SIZE; i++ ) printf( "%.1f ", max_values[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
25.9 25.7 25.4
```

It seems you was expecting this result.:)

Comment: I like that approach too `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Glad to see you.:)

Comment: can do in C programming?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow got it Thanks!